# Which version of Chrome supported Flash?

Tags: google-chrome, flash

I'm pretty sure that Google Chrome used to allow the Flash plugin to run, but now, I am having lots of `err_connection` issues on sites that require Flash when I open then in Chrome. Other browsers display these sites just fine.

What was the last version of Google Chrome that allowed the Flash plugin to run?

Note: I know I'll have to disable Chrome's auto-updates for this to work.

Comment: I'm not completely clear about your reference to Flash. Are you looking to remove the poorly-designed, buggy, giant-security-hole, piece -of-crap known as Flash, or are you wanting to risk all the problems you expose yourself to without the frequent Flash updates required to plug the leaky boat?

Comment: Why did everyone downvote my comment? It was a fair question.

Comment: @MaximTeleguz Although I did not downvote the question, I would guess some of the reasons behind it have to do with how your question was phrased. From my perspective, I'd have to concur with the reasons it was put on hold (although I made an attempt to discern what you're asking), and it did come across more as a rant than anything. I would suggest editing it to get more to the core of what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: @Brian it did seem like you understood fairly well; and to some pedigree i feel like the admins also understood very well what i was asking. The question was a question that i wanted answers too. So why does it matter so much to them?

Comment: Just as a note, it wasn't admins who downvoted your question or who closed it. It was members of the community who have spent time and effort on the site and have built up the reputation points through that time and effort to have achieved the ability to vote to close questions. It matters to us that questions on SuperUser have the chance to have a good and accurate answer. Questions where the "right" answer is up to the opinion of the asker are not a good fit, and are therefore closed.

Comment: It would actually be a very simple edit to make this question not opinion-based and make it a good fit for the site: Remove the first line or rephrase it, and change the question line to "What was the last version of Google Chrome that allowed Flash to run?"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Google Chrome version 45 was the first build released that removed support for the Netscape Plugin API (off which Flash interfaces with Chrome), which would make the last supported build 44.0.2403.157. [It is available on FileHippo](http://filehippo.com/download_google_chrome/62867/).

Per [some official documentation for Chromium](https://www.chromium.org/administrators/turning-off-auto-updates) (Google Chrome's open-source base):

> To turn off auto-updates of Google Chrome on Windows, you need to instruct Google Update to not update it.  To do this, you can either:
>
> 1. Use the Google Update ADM templates provided on this page or as described in this article.
> 2. Set the value of HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Update\AutoUpdateCheckPeriodMinutes to the REG_DWORD value of "0".

Here's a sample reg file source for the latter option:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Update\AutoUpdateCheckPeriodMinutes]
"AutoUpdateCheckPeriodMinutes"=dword:00000000
```

All this in mind, I would reconsider what you are really trying to accomplish. This build is at least 2 months old (excluding you from future developments) and leaves you open to security vulnerabilities in Flash. I would advise utilizing this only for when Flash is really necessary, and keep your other everyday browsing elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. This is exactly what i was looking for.